# Windows 10 unable to exit safe mode

Tags: windows-10, passwords, microsoft-account

I put my PC into safe mode to diagnose an issue I was having with Windows 10. But now, I can neither log in nor exit safe mode. My account is set up to log in by PIN, but I get the error `Something happened and your PIN isn't available. Click to set up your PIN again`. Clicking the button doesn't do anything.

The usual options in the power menu like `reset this PC` are all behind a password. I don't remember the password to this user account since I have been using my PIN to login for years. The account is an online Microsoft account, but resetting the password online didn't help - it doesn't accept the new password either.

Is there anything I can do to recover the PC without flashing a new ISO? Specifically recover the system itself - the important files are all backed up so no worries there.

I do have a Linux machine I can plug the drive into. Is there a tool I can use to undo the `msconfig` change I did to put the computer in safe mode?

Comment: Try running a Windows 10 Repair Install from Safe Mode (you need networking in Safe Mode).     https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/something-happened-and-your-pin-isnt-available/0af5525d-a37d-4dbd-8046-4918c8aefc53 some more specific suggestions here may help

Comment: I'll try those once I get the repair install usb working

Comment: @John can you please elaborate on the steps I need to take? Any kind of repair options are behind a password when I boot from that target machine. I can boot from a USB, but then I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: You said you got into Safe Mode  and if you have network then the link should work.  If not and there is nothing else you can do , then it is time for a fresh install.

Comment: By repair install do you mean booting from a USB and performing a repair install? I tried that, and it says that it failed, but the log file shows no errors, and that the root cause is `Boot status indicates that the OS booted successfully`

Comment: Windows needs to be running to do a Repair Install. So then my suggestion was to try in Safe Mode with Networking. If that does not work / no feasible then you need to do a fresh install.

Comment: That's the problem - I'm stuck in safe mode. I cannot log in since the PIN entry is broken in safe mode for whatever reason. I'm not sure how the link you posted relates to that

Comment: It now time to reinstall Windows. Hopefully you have major files  backed up